# how to customize xaxis of highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am stuck in an minor issue(for me it's not minor at all). It seems the Highcharts binds its x and y Axis for somewhat relation(like point to point is corresponding), what i am trying to do is set some label and tick Interval for xAxis for some reason, without relating it to y Axis.

For instance: I have 400 points to display on the chart, but my x would start at 200, and end at 600. however, when I was doing it, 200 points of the charts was chopped and meanwhile 200 are left for blank.

Anyone could tell me the reason and show me a path out?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that the axes are related, it's that your data has an inherent `x` value whether or not you've specified one - your first point has an `x` value of `0`, and they increment from there.

If you want to start the x axis at something other than `0`, you have options:

**1)** specify the x value for each data point.  Rather than send an array of `y` values, such as `[5,6,9]`, for example, you can send your data as `x,y` pairs, like `[[2,5],[3,6],[4,9]]`

This method gives you the flexibility to plot data that does not follow a uniform interval, e.g. `[[2,5],[17,6],[58,9]]`, which will plot each point at its specified `x` value appropriately.

**2)** Use the `pointStart` and `pointInterval` properties in your `plotOptions`

So, in your case, something like:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    pointStart: 200,
    pointInterval: 1
  }
}
```

This tells the chart that your first point has an `x` value of `200`, and each point after that increments by `1` axis unit.

**Reference:**

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointStart
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointInterval

Comment: The problem is, the data comes from real world so i may not be able to setup it previous to what has been sent to the UI side. Actually I am doing a project for Spectrum display, so when every frame of data comes, i have to dynamically change the ticks

Comment: So, you need to either 1) keep track of your offset, and set that as the `pointStart` each time, or 2) send the data as `[x, y]` pairs.